# Responsive website turns white on iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone, responsive-design

I am making a responsive website, which works on different screens on pc's.
But my media query for the iPhone seems to work not properly. When I launch the website it displayed incorrect. When I refresh 2 things can happen: It turns into the correct display, or it turns the whole page white. Refreshing then keeps the screen white.

This is my css media query:

```
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 320px) and (max-device-width : 480px)
{

    body
    {
        overflow-x:hidden;  
    }

    section#info
    {
        width:90%;
        font-size:350%; 
        height:auto;
        font-family:Futura;
    }

    section#infoMeenemen
    {
        width:90%;
        font-size:350%; 
        height:auto;
        font-family:Futura;
    }

    nav
    {
        min-width:90%;
        top:12.5%;
        margin-left:2.5%;
        font-size:175%; 
        font-family:Futura; 
    }

    div#navigationSection
    {
        min-height:300px;
    }

    div#newsSection
    {
        min-height:430px;
        font-size:175%;
    }

    section#news
    {
        padding-top:6%;
        text-align:center;
        font-family:Futura;
        font-size:1.3em;
    }

    section#food
    {
        text-align:center;
    }   

    #imgLunch
    {
        display:block;
        margin-left:0%;
        min-width:100%;
    }

    #imgHightea
    {
        display:block;
        margin-left:0%;
        min-width:100%;
    }

    #imgLekkers
    {
        display:block;
        margin-left:0%;
        min-width:100%;
    }

    section#food
    {
        font-size:300%; 
        font-family:Futura;
    }

    section#food img
    {
        min-width:80%;
    }

    footer
    {
        font-size:150%;
        height:600px;
    }

    #footerBack
    {
        background-color:black; 
    }

    article#tijden
    {
        margin-left:4%; 
        float:left;
        width:40%;
    }

    article#informatie
    {
        float:left;
        width:40%;  
    }

    article#werken
    {
        width:80%;
    }   

    footer article
    {
        height:auto;
        font-family:Futura;
        color:white;
    }
```

Comment: do you have this `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">` on your `head` tag? 

plus give us some HTML code so we can help you better.

Comment: are your elements positioned ```fixed``` or ```absolute```?